# Rebuilding sales_order_grid

Tags: magento2, database

`sales_order_grid` is missing some orders that are in `sales_order`. How can the grid table be rebuilt? It does not appear part of the indexer or other cli commands.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Go to Advanced - Developer - Grid Settings
2. Set Asynchronous Indexing to "Enable"
3. Flush cache
4. Go to database table "sales_order_grid". You can truncate this table or remove only orders during some period where orders missing (from X day to current day).
5. Make sure what cron is configured and works. (I don't like configure run cron on my local PC, so I run command `while :; do sleep 60; ./bin/magento cron:run & done` when I need cron and stop it when I don't need it any more)
6. Please, wait for about 2-3 minutes...
7. Done.

Comment: Is it possible to rebuild sales_order_grid without cron somehow, may be by using some console command?

Comment: In any case, you can run any cron manually via magerun https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Reviwe list of cron commands - php ./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:list
and run cron like - php ./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run sales_grid_order_async_insert

Comment: But if you are in a Production environment?
You haven't Advanced - Developer configuration so 'dev/grid/async_indexing' path hasn't a value and sync cron doesn't work.


    `public function asyncInsert()
    {
        if ($this->globalConfig->getValue('dev/grid/async_indexing')) {
            $this->entityGrid->refreshBySchedule();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

create sandbox script

**`<magento root>/sandbox/testAsyncGrid.php`**

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
set_time_limit(0);

/*
 * Turn off output buffering
 */
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}

require_once '../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('crontab');

//Set php to display errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Start timer
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());

    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

//don't print anything to the screen until end of script or buffer is full.
ob_start();

/** @var SalesOrderIndexGridAsyncInsertCron $obj */
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get('SalesOrderIndexGridAsyncInsertCron');

$obj->execute();
```