# Magento 2.4.2 Order Status stuck on processing

Tags: invoice, order-status, shipment, creditmemo

When an order comes in an invoice is created automatically and gets send out. I can also find that invoice when i click on the order. If I ship the order then, the shipment email goes out to the costumer but the process is still on processing in the order overview but not in the order itself. If i go on shipments then there is also no shipment shown. The same problem comes up with a credit memo.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data in grid comes from separate table `sales_order_grid`. The magento updates this table by cron. Please check that your cron properly configured and run.

Also maybe this one topic will be in interest [Rebuilding sales_order_grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209292/rebuilding-sales-order-grid)